# What is the proper way to restart an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

In this Electron documentation [page](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprelaunchoptions), they recommend that to restart an application, one should execute `app.quit` or `app.exit` *after* the call to `app.relaunch`:

> Note that this method does not quit the app when executed, you have to call app.quit or app.exit after calling app.relaunch to make the app restart.

However after experimenting I found that the order doesn't seem to actually matter. *(See my example below.)*

I know that `app.quit` and `app.exit` are not quite the same. The former can be interrupted and will trigger some events while the latter will force the app to exit without triggering any events or allowing the app to cancel the action.

**Question**: assuming that it is always ok to force the app to exit and that we don't have any tasks to perform before the app exits, is there:

1. A reason to prefer `app.quit` or `app.exit`?
2. A reason why one must run `app.quit` or `app.exit` after `app.relaunch`?

---

Here's a very simple Electron app:

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "burrito",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^4"
  }
}
```

*main.js*

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron');
let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(
    Menu.buildFromTemplate([
      {role: 'appMenu', submenu: [

        {label: 'relaunch(); exit()', click() {
          app.relaunch();
          app.exit();
        }},

        {label: 'relaunch(); quit()', click() {
          app.relaunch();
          app.quit();
        }},

        {type: 'separator'},

        {label: 'exit(); relaunch()', click() {
          app.exit();
          app.relaunch();
        }},

        {label: 'quit(); relaunch()', click() {
          app.quit();
          app.relaunch();
        }}
      ]}
    ])
  );
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 640, height: 480});
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
});
```

Producing the following application menu:

[image]

A click on any of the menu item will produce the same result: the app quits then restarts.

Answer (score 28):

The proper way to restart an electron app is:

```
app.relaunch()
app.exit()
```

See [official documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprelaunchoptions).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Actually, it just confirms what the OP said: _"one should execute `app.quit` or `app.exit` after the call to `app.relaunch`"_

Answer (score 16):

## `app.relaunch`

According to `app.relaunch` [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app/#apprelaunchoptions):

> Relaunches the app when current instance exits.
>
> (...)
>
> Note that this method does not quit the app when executed, you have to call `app.quit` or `app.exit` after calling `app.relaunch` to make the app restart.
>
> When `app.relaunch` is called for multiple times, multiple instances will be started after current instance exited.

We can assume that:

1. Calling `app.relaunch()` only won't do anything (until the user closes the application, then it will restart);
2. You can call `app.quit()` or `app.exit()` in order to close the application, then it will restart because you already called `app.relaunch()`.

## `app.quit`

Citing the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app/#appquit) again:

> Try to close all windows. The `before-quit` event will be emitted first. If all windows are successfully closed, the `will-quit` event will be emitted and by default the application will terminate.
>
> This method guarantees that all `beforeunload` and `unload` event handlers are correctly executed. It is possible that a window cancels the quitting by returning `false` in the `beforeunload` event handler.

It means that using **`app.quit()` may or may not terminate the application**.

## `app.exit`

The [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app/#appexitexitcode) states:

> All windows will be closed immediately without asking the user, and the `before-quit` and `will-quit` events will not be emitted.

So, *immediately* is a dangerous word. It means that the app will be closed *as soon as it is possible*, and that **it certainly will close, but not instantly**.

## Should I use `app.quit` or `app.exit`?

Both are valid, depends on your use case:

- If your user may be on a screen where you have some validations to prevent they from closing the app because of reasons, **`app.quit` is probably better for you**. Just be careful to not call `app.relaunch` more than once (it causes multiple instances to be started after exiting the current instance):

```js
app.relaunch();
app.quit(); // maybe the application will be closed; maybe not
```

- If you need (or want) to close the app immediately in order to apply some setting, for example, no matter what is happening in that moment, **you should call `app.exit`**. Doing it you are safe that the app will be closed and relaunched:

```js
app.relaunch();
app.exit(); // the application will be closed as soon as possible
```

## Why should I call `app.relaunch` first?

Well, because it is logical. See the code below:

```js
app.exit();
app.relaunch();
```

You're telling: *"Hey, Electron, please close my app. Oh, and restart it after closing."*. It'll work most of the times, but only because `app.exit` is slower than `app.relaunch` to execute. They're not running synchronously.

If, for some reason, Electron terminates your application before knowing it should be relaunched, it would be an unexpected behavior for you, but that's what you told Electron to do.

Answer (score 5):

1. `quit` gracefully closes all the windows then exits, compared to `exit` which simply terminates the application with no regard to anything else, like `process.exit` in Node. You'll want to use `quit` in most situations for safety.
2. It is preferred to call `relaunch` first to prevent race conditions. This will almost never happen in production because of how the event loop works, but it's just good practice.

Comment: What kind of race condition are you thinking of? Do you have an example of something that can happen during development that `app.relaunch(); app.quit()` (in that order) would mitigate and wouldn't happen in production?